# Function expansion in terms of plane waves

Tags: fourier-transform, plane-wave

I would like to expand a function $f(r)$ in terms of plane waves of the form $e^{ikr}$. With expansion coefficients $f_k$, one can write

$$ f(r) = \sum_kf_k e^{ikr}. $$

Now I need the coefficients $f_k$ which is what I need help with. My textbook tells me that by multiplying both sides of the equation by $e^{-ikr}/V$ and integrating over some volume $V$, one gets

$$ f_k = \frac{1}{V}\int_V\mathop{d^3r} e^{-ikr} f(r).$$

Unfortunately, I can't quite figure out how to get rid of the sum for example. I would be glad if someone could show me how to determine the expansion coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

It is better to relabel the sum index $k \mapsto l$:

$e^{-ikr}/V \sum_l f_l e^{ilr} = \sum_l f_le^{i(l-k)r}/V$.

By linearity of Integration and the General identity (holds for any number $p$ )

$\int_V d^3re^{ipr} = V \delta_{p,0}$ (*) you are done.

The function $\delta_{p,0}$ is the Kronecker delta and has the value 1 for $p=0$ and Zero otherwise (with this you can get rid of the sum).

To prove the identity $*$, simply perform Integration over the three space coordinates, use Euler's identity for exponential of complex numbers and the fact that the function

$sin(px)/p, p \mapsto \infty$ is Zero for $x = n\pi/p$ ($n$ arbitrary integer), but for the Special case $n=0$ it is nonvanishing.